# Typescript type annotation in get/post requests

Tags: typescript, vue.js

```
function handleLogin() {
  isLoggingIn.value = true;
  loginInstance
    .post("login/", {
      ...login.value,
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      localStorage.setItem("frontend", data.token);
      store.commit("setToken", data.token);
     
      getServiceList();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      error.value = err?.response?.data;
      const errorMsg = `Something went wrong ${
        err?.response?.data?.non_field_errors ?? ""
      }`;
      handleErrorMessage(flashMessage, errorMsg);
    })
    .finally(() => (isLoggingIn.value = false));
}
```

how do i assign typescript type to data?
it throws the error "property 'token' does not exist on type 'unknown'"

Comment: What is loginInstance? Is it an axios instance? Then you should be able to do `.post<YourType>("login/"...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to assign a custom interface to the type `data`, as it's taken as `unknown` type by default. With an unknown type object, you just can't access properties before casting (take a fast read of https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript). You gotta create an interface or type for your request, for example:

```
interface IRequest {
   token: String;
}
```

Then, you gotta say to TypeScript the object `data` is that type, for example like this:

```
// ...
  loginInstance
    .post("login/", {
      ...login.value,
    })
    .then(({ data: IRequest }) => {
// ...
```

You can also make a one line type definition like this:

```
// ...
  loginInstance
    .post("login/", {
      ...login.value,
    })
    .then(({ data: { token: String } }) => {
// ...
```

*Take in consideration this will crash if the object `data` is not an object with the property `token` as a string. TypeScript is made for type-safe purposes and well... this is... type safe.*

**Note:** As suggested in comments, if you're using a library with in-built TypeScript support like Axios, you may be able to do something similar to this:

```
interface IRequest {
   token: String;
}

// ...
loginInstance
    .post<IRequest>("login/", {
      ...login.value,
    })
    .then(data) => {
      // Here, data will be already
      // interpreted as an `IRequest` type
// ...
```